# What's the difference between `getCacheKeyInfo` and `_getCacheId`?

Tags: blocks, cache, holepunching

What's the difference between `getCacheKeyInfo` and `_getCacheId`?
Why `_getCacheId` is not enough to cache a block?

Answer (score 3):

`getCacheKeyInfo` is used to determine the cache key if one is not set directly for blocks.
It is used in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::getCacheKey()` that is used `_loadCache` method on the same block
`_getCacheId` is not used at all for block caching and it is deprecated starting `CE 1.4.0.0-alpha3`.
Honestly I have no idea what was the use if it before 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

After `1.4.0.0-alpha`, magento **deprecated**  `_getCacheId()` may be in order to improve `Mage_Core_Model_Cache`.

You  see more details about deprecated from 1.5.0 and check this link at http://docs.databyte.at/magento/community/1.5/deprecated.html

Now `getCacheKeyInfo()` use for cache